# Strangely placed definite article and "dar"

Tags: grammar-identification

> Gehen sie auf folgende Punkte ein:
>
> Stellen Sie kurz die fuer die wichtigsten Ergebnisse der Grafik dar
> [image]
>
> Deutsch intensiv C1 Schreiben

In the exercise question, there are two parts I don't understand.

1. What does the 'die' mean after kurz?
2. What does 'dar' mean at the end?

Comment: So you're saying the die is wrong? @Stephie

Comment: Yes I believe so @Carsten S

Comment: I think @CarstenS wanted to emphasize that "intesiv" is missing an "n": *intensiv*. In addition it should be "Deutsch intensiv", niot "Deutsch Intensiv", because "intensiv" is an adjective and they are not capitalised at all.

Comment: @CarstenS Meines  Erachtens ist es am produktivsten, klar erkennbare Rechtschreibfehler stillschweigend zu korrigieren. Alles andere führt nur zu unnötigen Kommentaren (wie hier geschehen). Siehe auch: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/331/35111

Comment: @DavidVogt, mein Fehler, ich dachte, das wäre Teil des Screenshots und damit ein Indikator für die Qualität der Quelle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two very different and unrelated questions here (giving you the benefit of the doubt and not voting to close):

1. The „dar“ is part of the verb “[darstellen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/darstellen)” (meaning 3, to describe, explain), separated.
2. This is where either something is a) *missing* or b) *two words in excess* or c) it’s a *typo*:

> a) Stellen Sie kurz die für die [missing object: for whom? E.g. “die Befragten”, “die Leser”, … or something like that] wichtigsten Ergebnisse der Grafik dar.

or

> b) Stellen Sie kurz die <del>für die</del> wichtigsten Ergebnisse der Grafik dar.

or

> c) Stellen Sie kurz die für *Sie* wichtigsten Ergebnisse der Grafik dar.

Comment: I guess the second "die" should have been a "Sie"; in fact I had to read it twice to realize it does not say "die für Sie wichtigsten Ergebnisse"... . But I agree the "die" belongs to "Ergebnisse" as in "stellen Sie kurz die Ergebnisse dar".

Comment: @GuntramBlohm or that. Will amend my answer, thanks.